# Logstash not able to pass data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using a **Logstash server 1-> Kafka -> Logstash server 2-> Elasticsearch -> Kibana** setup. Below is the configuration files from Logstash server 2 .

1) 03-logstash-logs-kafka-consumer.conf

```
input {
  kafka {
    zk_connect => 'zk_netaddress:2181'
    topic_id => 'logstash_logs'
    codec => "json"
  }
}
output{
  stdout{}
}
```

2) 30-elasticsearch-output.conf

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Though Logs are travelling from Logstash server 1 to Logstash server 2 through Kafka and Logstash server 2 can also output to the `/var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout` file, Logstash server 2 is not able to output to the elasticsearch configured with it. I have checked all services, they are running well and there are no Exception in the logs of all the services.
Please post your suggestions.

Comment: Can you post the input block of your logstash server 2.

Comment: How are you launching the logstash server 2? If the second file (30-elasticsearch-output.conf) is not used by the configuration, nothing will be sent to Elasticsearch.

Comment: input {
  kafka {
    zk_connect => 'zk_netaddress:2181'
    topic_id => 'logstash_logs'
    codec => "json"
  }
}     is input block to Logstash server 2..

Comment: @baudsp .. by executing command  "/etc/init.d/logstash start"    launching Logstash server. Other stdout output configuration is consumed and used correctly. On same place elasticsearch output has been put.  How we can verify elasticsearch output file is not being used?

Comment: To check if the output file is not being used, you can add a mistake in the configuration (for example, replace hosts by host);  if the logstash fail to launch with a configuration error, you are sure this file is being used. I use the -f option to specify the configuration files to use, so I though you might have forgotten to add one file.

Comment: @baudsp... I did as you mentioned and Logstash starting giving error of configuration... so it is considering that file... Please let me know if you have any more suggestion ....  Thanks a lot for quick replies....

Comment: Sorry. All the other possibility that I can think of would result in errors appearing in the logs/outputs.

Comment: You can ask your question on the elastic forum, in their logstash category: https://discuss.elastic.co/c/logstash. There's a chance someone might have an idea.